# Refreshtoken how to set offline access_type for the v3 Google API

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-oauth

Im building an "installed" application in c# to retrieve Google Analytics data. I'm using version 3 of the api. The challenge is to set the access type to offline, for the no user interaction. But I can't see how to do this by the API. I searched the code samples but most of them seems to be outdated. I'm currently using the oauth 2.0 for authentication.
So I'm looking for a way to use the api to specify the offline mode while sending requests to the api

Comment: Just a little update, it is the grant_type as specifiec here I'm looking for https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

Comment: you only want to access your personal GA Data? or do you want others to be able to access there data though your app?

Comment: That link you posted is on dealing with the refresh token. You dont need to worry about that.  As long as you save the refreshtoken and use it next time your all set.  As far as getting new access tokens the v3 of the API handles that for you.

Comment: Ohhh just testing my code again, actually found a lot of help in your blog posts, great work! I'm very interested in a way to trigger the refresh of the access token, to ensure that it happens behind the scenes, and don't prompt with a browser. I'm running this on a server as a service at least after the initial run where the first token is generated.

Comment: Ahhh everything seems to work now. I reduced the expireInSeconds an outputs the accesstoken after each request. Here I can see when it changes. Next up will be implement my own storage. I tried before but could not see the storeAsync method being triggered by the api.